# How to make Firefox open RSS directly (like other XML files), instead of downloading?

Tags: firefox, rss

Using Firefox 70.0.1 on Arch Linux. (I realize that this question might technically belong on SuperUser, but I suspect that no non-developer would ever need to do this.)

I'm trying to debug my code that generates an RSS feed, by viewing it directly in Firefox's XML viewer.

When I enter a feed URL, like https://en.blog.wordpress.com/feed/, Firefox pops up the dialog that asks me what to do with the file. It calls it an "RSS Summary", and I can choose to open it or save it to disk.

I can choose to open it in Firefox, but then the file is *first* downloaded to disk, and then opened from a `file://` URL. The result is that I can't hit F5 to refresh it; I have to enter the URL anew.

This only happens if the `Content-Type` header is `application/rss+xml`. A file served up as plain `application/xml` (like e.g. https://xkcd.com/rss.xml uses) is opened directly.

How can I tell Firefox that `application/rss+xml` should receive the same treatment and just be viewed as a regular XML file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to achieve this using an extension.

There is [Open in Browser](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/open-in-browser/) which seems to resolve the issue.

When you try opening the RSS URL with the extension installed, you will be shown a window where you can choose which action to take. You can choose to open the file as XML in the browser window. If you want to be able to hit F5 and reload the file, you may also want to tick "Do this automatically for files like this from now on".

Note that I haven't read the source code of the extension so I don't know if it is safe to use or not.

Comment: Perfect! I can even open it as XML and get all the highlighting and folding goodies.

Answer (score 2):

Add the „view-source:“ prefix in front of your url as said in this article: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/view-source-of-rss-feed-in-firefox/

Comment: Ah, of course, that's already a big improvement! I can work with this, but it would be nice to get the full "XML viewer" experience with highlighting and folding.

Comment: I saw that, but it's from 2011 and there no longer is such an option. The built-in feed reader that Firefox used to have has since been removed.

Comment: I'm sorry to unaccept your answer. It worked at the time, but as of Firefox 80 (maybe earlier) it no longer does the trick :(